Change score as predictor
I want to see if a change in an independent variable (T2-T1) predicts another variable at T2. For example, higher increases in cognitive impairment over 1 year for people with dementia predict lower quality of life.
My question is: do I need to control for baseline quality of life (dependent variable)?
I've already read that I shouldn't control for the IV, but not sure about the DV.

As discussed further here there are many serious problems with change scores.  When analyzing change in an independent variable it is usually the case that the most recent measurement best predicts the response variable.  Contrast that with the subtraction of post - pre which gives a lot of weight to pre.  Fit the model with pre and post instead.
But you have another problem as your T1 and T2 are not baseline times but T2 is also the time at which the response is measured (quality of life).  This creates a circularity that is hard to interpret.  Most of the time you need the response such as QOL to be measured at T3 > T2, and you condition on covariates measured at T1 and T2.
